# AsyncTask vs Activity.runOnUiThread() vs Handler.post()

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I'm studying the code of a large app. There are 3 asynchrony patterns used in the UI, all of them seem equivalent:

**Pattern 1, AsyncTask**

```
new AsyncTask<X, Void, Z>() {  
    protected Boolean doInBackground(X... params) {  
        //background task  
    }  

    protected void onPostExecute(Z res) {  
        //UI callback  
    }  
}.execute();
```

**Pattern 2, Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)**

```
new Thread() {  
    public void run() {  
        //background task  

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
            public void run() {  
                //UI callback  
            }  
        });  
    }  
}.start();
```

**Pattern 3, Handler.post(Runnable)**

```
new Thread() {  
    public void run() {  
        //background task  

        handler.post(new Runnable() {  
            public void run() {  
                //UI callback  
            }  
        });  
    }  
}.start();
```

**Questions:**

- Any difference between the 3 patterns that I'm missing? (Besides AsyncTask being run on a pre-existing thread pool with background priority.)
- Any cases where a particular pattern would be preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are all really a `Handler` either visibly or internally.

`AsyncTask#finish()` that calls `onPostExecute()` is called from a `Handler` message loop.

`runOnUiThread()` posts the `Runnable` to a `Handler` if the current thread is not the UI thread. If it is the UI thread, the runnable is executed synchronously - this is not always desirable.

Directly using a `Handler` gives you low level control and only that.

What to use depends on your specific requirements.