# Auto updating UI with a different thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an Android App which constantly auto updating a list of data from the App's SQLite which an ArrayAdapter is used for handling the data, So for this I've made another thread or handler from the onCreate method of the Acitivity, and inside it's code there's a continuous loop for updating then waiting (or sleeping the thread for a moment, ex/ 10 sec), There are two problems involved:
1- Only the UI thread can touch it's views (though I only touched ArrayAdapter if it counts as a View).
2- Once the other thread starts to run, The UI thread seems to stuck in it, and won't update even the first UI update (complete white).
codes for the autoUpdate() method: (which is called on the last line of the UI onCreate method):

```
public void startAutoUpdateLogData(final int milliseconds){
    continueAutoUpdate = true;
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(continueAutoUpdate){
                try{
                    Log.v("updating..", "");
                    updateLogFromDatabase();
                    Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

OR:

```
public void startAutoUpdateLogData2(final int milliseconds){
    continueAutoUpdate = true;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(continueAutoUpdate){
                try{
                    Log.e("updating...", "");
                    updateLogFromDatabase();
                    Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

OR

```
public void startAutoUpdateLogData3(final int milliseconds){
    continueAutoUpdate = true;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(continueAutoUpdate){
                try{
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            Log.e("updating...", "");
                            updateLogFromDatabase();
                        }
                    }, milliseconds);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Neither of these work.

Comment: First: If your code doe snot work then most likely because your `updateLogFromDatabase` implementation is defect. *Second*: An endless loop with `sleep` is pretty bad - that is busy waiting. Wherever you write to the database create a "dirty" signal or try to use the SQLite system to get notified when data changes.

Comment: Second and Third solution while loop block the main UI  thread, because runOnUIThread will run on main thread. As expected.

Comment: @Robert updateLogFromDatabase() is very safe, another reason in using auto updating every 10 secs, is to update display updated time from now ( ex/ 1hrs ago, Just now..). which if there's not  a database change, still updating display date-time every 10 seconds.

Comment: @lib4 yeah you're right, There should be another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do many ways. But this one will be more closer solution to what you have done.

```
private void runThread() {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (continueAutoUpdate) {
                try {
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            Log.e("updating...", "");
                            updateLogFromDatabase();
                        }
                    }, milliseconds);
                    Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: isn't it the same?, even doubling the wait time.

Comment: This is not same , please see carefully. This is not any of the solution u have provided in your question. You should try this. please, I didnt used runOnUIthread

Comment: What exactly the error u r getting? Please post the code for updateLogFromDatabase(); , please explain what error you are getting.

Comment: white screen (Not building initial UI), which indicates that the main ui thread is stuck and still inside the loop.

Comment: Is it printing the log Log.e("updating...", ""); ? It seems blank change like this Log.e("updating...", "Updating...");

Comment: If your solution works then the solution which I posted also should work. You have used runOnUithread. I have used a handler. Better to use Handler. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33531519/2470770 . Happy Coding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162539/discussion-between-lib4-and-jihad-mehdi).

Comment: speed can be controlled by milliseconds provided in handler, give shorter time for quick response. Always better to deal with handler. and you can control the number of request you post to handler and decide which one to operate on and which one to ignore.  Dont give any delay to handler then it will be fast as uiThread.

Answer (score 1):

After trying various stuff, I finally found the solution: Anytime you have some long-run tasks to perform, you can assign a new Java thread to execute it, but when there's a need to update the UI from that thread, which can't be directly accessing any components of the UI, So in that case you only need to wrap the code with runOnUiThread() inside the other thread. ex/

```
private void startAutoUpdateLogData(final int milliseconds) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    continueAutoUpdate = true;

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (continueAutoUpdate) {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.e("updating...", "");
                            updateLogFromDatabase();
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```